Rviz2 display nothing after window minimized
working properly at first

After click minimize button and reopen it. The orge display is disappered.
No error message in terminal even with start rviz with "-l"

Ubuntu 22.04 with ros2 humble
cpu 11800h with rtx3060 using nvidia 535 driver
Things I have try.

Install diffrent version of gpu driver (545 555 Nouveau)
Try to run rvize in diffrent desktop enviroments(gnome mate budige)
Switch gpu betwen intel uhd770 and rtx3060 by nvidia prime


I think I fixed it. I follow this blog upgrade my mesa. I found it does not solve the isssue, but after I remove it reinstall the original mesa, the issue solved. It must be some problem due to mesa installation.
